# How to avoid logoff in WS2012 after "start a program on connection" for Admin?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I enabled the "start a program on connection". I wanted to use it for users.

The problem, is that now, when I access as Administrator, the app is also executed and when I close the app, it also logs off the session.

How can I log in to Windows Server 2012 as Administrator to disable this change?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways you could take care of this, but unless you've restricted Task Manager the easiest thing to do is to logon with your Administrator user, send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd>, start Task Manager, and use the "New Task..." function to start a copy of `explorer.exe`. Then you'll have the familiar Windows UI and can clean up the change you made.

You probably should investigate the [Multiple Local Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731758.aspx) feature, which can be used to create a local Group Policy that doesn't apply to Administrator users.

Comment: I wasted the entire day trying to user PowerShell via remote connection. Your solution works as a charm. By the way, Ctrl+Alt+Del did not work in RDC but easily I have found the solution: Ctrl + Alt + End. You saved my week (my plan B was to reinstall the server). Thank you.